# Add "Keep me signed in" functionality to web application

Tags: jquery, html, spring-mvc

Our web application is a Spring 2.5 application, using HTML, JQuery front end. We have an enhancement to add "Keep me signed in" functionality.
Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this functionality.

Any help on above would be highly appriciated.

-V

Answer (score 0):

use **cookie** achieve this functionality.

see for more detail [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)